# Tips for working with yarn that splits easily?

Tags: crocheting, yarn

I just started crocheting with a medium weight Viscose, Polyester, Nylon blend yarn and it likes to split a lot while I'm doing front post and back post double crochets as well as some other stitches. Does anyone have any tips on how to avoid splitting while I'm crocheting with these types of yarn?

Comment: By splitting, do you mean the component threads separate? Is it just at the loose end or in the middle of the yarn? If it's in the middle of the yarn, could it be reduced by pre-tightening the twist in the yarn (twirling the end to add more twist)? Any chance you can grab a snapshot of the problem and add it to the question?

Comment: @fixer1234 Sorry that this response is very late. It is splitting in the center and at the ends. It feels like the yarn just wants to fall apart most of the time.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to give it more twist, possibly split it and re-twine it. But that will change the way the yarn looks.

The best is just to work careful and make sure you always have the whole of the yarn when you pick up a stitch and when you go round the yarn with the hook.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that the yarn is fraying at the end, you could try melting it together. All those are synthetic fibers that would melt at high enough heat. I would try ironing the end between sheets of wax paper